# How to get menu breadcrumbs to appear in the navigation bar in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, navigation, breadcrumbs

I am using menu breadcrumb module in drupal 7, and the breadcrumbs appear at the top of my finished pages, underneath the navigation bar- How can I get them to appear within it?

If this is not possible, are there any suggestions for a breadcrumb module to use that will appear where I want it and give a similar result?

Comment: Presumably by 'at the top of my finished pages' you mean within the content zone containing the node/page. To make them appear in the navigation bar, menu breadcrumb would need to provide a block, which you can put in a zone other than the content zone containing the node/page - try taking a look at http://drupal.org/project/issues/menu_breadcrumb?text=block&status=All

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. I will look at the page you've suggested, thanks.

Comment: And yes, menu breadcrumb does what we want it to. I was trying to make it appear in the same place as the previous one. If you don't think this is necessary then that's fine?

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/breadcrumb
Expose a block containing the breadcrumb.

There is no download but you can get it with git http://drupal.org/node/3229/git-instructions

Answer (score 0):

Use your css.

---

The easiest way to move around things in drupal is editing the css files that control the location of each element.

The location depends on the theme you are using and I would strongly suggest that if you do not use a custom theme use one so you won't break the default files.

the css is usually located in `sites/themes/themeName/CSS`

Answer (score 0):

in your drupal folder, go to `sites/all/themes/YourTheme/templates/page.tpl.php` and open it in notepad (or, better yet, notepad++) and look for "breadcrumb". The piece of code will look like this:

```
<?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
    <div id="breadcrumb"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Moving it to the navigation header in the php file will make it render in this region. Make sure you make a subtheme of the theme you are currently using, since updating the theme to a new version will erase any custom changes you have made from the default version.